Screen resolution fixed at 800x600
I formatted my Windows 7 computer to 8.1, everything is fine. But the screenshot is fixed at 800x600. I tried to download the display drivers using plain logic, but the system replied that it is not supported. How do I solve this problem?

What exactly is “plain logic”? The resolution you have is what i would expect from the Microsoft Basic Display drivers. My suggestion go back to Windows 7 where you can download a driver for your device. Windows 7 and Windows 8 are equally unsupported by Microsoft, Intel, AMD, and Nvidia.

(That is, I searched by specifying the name of my site and tried to use the search result.) Your suggestion may be good, but I need to run Node JS 18 version. I will find another solution.

The oldest Windows version still under support - for less than a year though - is Windows 10.

You should [edit] your question to provide more details. What make and model is the computer? Does the manufacturer have compatible drivers for it? What is the graphics device? A lot more details are needed. Please do not post duplicate questions with even less information.

Instead of using unsupported versions of Windows, with no path to security updates, to run Node.js, it would make far more sense (and be far easier) to run it under a modern OS, such as a version of Linux.
Linux installers will automatically add the correct drivers for video. A current version will also get security patches. For example, Ubuntu 20.04, LTS (long-term service), with free PRO support, lists Apr 2030 for EOL. Even 32-bit machines could install v. 16.04, then upgrade to v. 18.04 lTS, good for another four years (unlike Windows 10, soon-to-be retired), or use any of the many other 32-bit versions.
Another option would be to install old Windows versions in a virtual machine running under a modern, supported version of Windows, if your PC can handle that. Many, such as VirtualBox, have prebuilt operating systems, easily installed.

What I want to create is a dynamic website, the screen resolution is exactly what I want and I want to get the result as fast as possible. Would it be better to work with Linux or should I continue with Windows?
